# How to clear distinct_id in mixpanel android when user logs out?

Tags: java, android, mixpanel

I need Mixpanel to forget distinct_id when user logs out.
In iOS app i call reset (https://mixpanel.com/site_media/doctyl/uploads/iPhone-spec/Classes/Mixpanel/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/Mixpanel/reset)
and it works.

I cant find the right call in Android mixpanel documentation, i tried calling clearSuperProperties(), but distinct_id persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Call `.clearSuperProperties()` to remove any Super Properties in local storage.
2. Set `new_distinct_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString());`
3. Call `.identify(new_distinct_id)` and `.getPeople().identify(new_distinct_id)`

This should wipe the device clean for a fresh user that can then register and be aliased to another `distinct_id`.

EDIT: The best way to do this with javascript is to delete the cookie. The name of the cookie is mp_{mixpanel_token_id}_mixpanel :)

Comment: We have written with Mixpanel about this, and this is their solution as well :( I agree that it is hardly ideal though.

Comment: not only is it not ideal, but I can't find this documented on their website. I'd think they'd have some clear documentation. Plus, they could easily create a clearIdentity function that does this.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's a reset() function in the MixpanelAPI class that, according to the doc, does the following : "Clears all distinct_ids, superProperties, and push registrations from persistent storage." 
Hope that helps

Comment: Problem with this is that on Logout I'd rather not clear super properties. I think a user specific call that clears identity, just like identify() creates a new one, would be better.